# buildTypes not working build.gradle Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android studio and I need to add:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

in my `build.gradle` Android Studio, but getting error:

> Gradle DSL method not found:'buildTypes()'

Comment: Have you nested the code above inside an `android { ... }` closure?

Comment: Please include your complete build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure buildTypes from "File-> Project Structure" and select your module, you can easily configure everything on the right side panel.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your build file is set up correctly?

The buildTypes have to be in the android closure. It should look something like this

**note: this is just a example you can't just copy and paste this**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.your.package"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

Hope this is of use for you